# Shall I accept, upvote all the right questions?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, accepted-answer, upvotes

I mean, in my recent [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44189394/instead-of-read-a-dictionary-by-keys-read-by-values-mydictkey-value-my), 3 users give me a right answer.

**Shall I accept all of them, the easiest to understand or the first?**

Also, 2 of the 3 users say almost the same answer, but the 3rd used a different method to resolve my problem, and this method I don't like (because I don't understand).

**Shall I accept his answer because it's a correct answer or not because I don't like it? Shall I downvote him?**

**Edit:**

 I just noticed that I can't accept multiples answers, so, Shall I accpet the easiest to understand or the first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only accept *one* answer, but you can upvote as many as you like.  If you feel like each of them helped you out, then upvoting would be acceptable.

In general, vote how you want to.  If the answer is genuinely useful, then it's fine to upvote; if the answer is genuinely poor or incorrect, then it's fine to downvote.  Don't vote based on impulse, though.

Comment: So I have to accept the most useful for me, right? Shall I upvote correct answers or **good** answers? I mean, answer with explanation and thing like that.

Comment: You don't *have* to vote on anything.  But if you want to, then vote on answers which you believe to be good, correct, and useful to others.